# Image not getting displayed in Laravel Ajax Crud

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, crud

I am trying to display the uploaded image on the `index.blade` but it is not getting displayed though the file path in the `<img>` tag is correct and also I checked on the console and it is also getting the correct path.
Controller for image store:

```
if($request->hasFile('profilepic')){
            $file = $request->file('profilepic');
            $profilepic=$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->storeAs('public/profile', $profilepic);
            $detail['profilepic'] = $profilepic;
        }

        if($request->hasFile('signature')){
            $file1 = $request->file('signature');
            $signature=$file1->getClientOriginalName();
            $file1->storeAs('public/sign', $signature);
            $detail['signature'] = $signature;
        }
        $detail->save();
        return response()->json([
            'status'=> 'success',
            'data' => $detail
        ]);
```

index.blade for img path

```
<td><img src="../storage/app/public/profile/{{ $detail->profilepic }}" width="100px"></td>
                <td><img src="storage/app/public/sign/{{ $detail->signature }}" width="100px"></td>
```

Ajax jquery:

```
 $(document).on('submit','.create_form',function(event)
            {
                event.preventDefault();
                const fd = new FormData(this);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "{{ route('details.store') }}",
                    data: fd,
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function(response)
                    {
                        $(".div3").load("{{ route('details.index') }}");
                    },
                    error: function(error)
                    {
                        console.log("Errors :",error);
                    }
                });
            });
```

[image: Image of console getting correct url for image location]

Also tried to put the `APP URL` from `.env` file in the `<img src>` but not working.

Comment: use src="{{asset('storage/profile/'.$detail->profilepic)}" and 
src="{{asset('storage/sign/'.$detail->signature )}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I listed below some things you can try to validate/troubleshoot your problem.

1. Ensure that the images are being stored correctly in the specified storage directory. Check the `public/profile` and `public/sign` directories to confirm that the images are saved there.
2. In Laravel, the files stored in the `storage/app/public` directory are not directly accessible. You need to create a symbolic link to make them accessible from the web. Run the following command in your terminal to create the symbolic link:

   ```
   php artisan storage:link
   ```

   This command will create a symbolic link from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public`. Make sure the symbolic link is created successfully.
3. Update the image source paths in your `index.blade` file to use the correct URL. Instead of using relative paths, use the `asset()` helper function to generate the correct URL based on the symbolic link:

   ```html
   <td><img src="{{ asset('storage/profile/' . $detail->profilepic) }}" width="100px"></td>
   <td><img src="{{ asset('storage/sign/' . $detail->signature) }}" width="100px"></td>
   ```

*Let us know about the outcome of the above troubleshooting!*